# Splitting Pandas Dataframe into chunks by Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

Let's say I have a pandas dataframe **df**

**DF**

```
Timestamp     Value
Jan 1 12:32   10
Jan 1 12:50   15
Jan 1 13:01   5
Jan 1 16:05   17
Jan 1 16:10   17
Jan 1 16:22   20
```

The result I want back, is a dataframe with per-hour (or any user specified time-segment, really) averages.  Let's say my specified **timesegment** is 1 hour here. I want back something like

```
Jan 1 12:00 12.5
Jan 1 13:00 5
Jan 1 14:00 0
Jan 1 15:00 0
Jan 1 16:00 18
```

Is there a simple way built into pandas to segment like this? It feels like there should be, but my googling of "splitting pandas dataframe" in a variety of ways is failing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to convert to datetime first then do `resample`

```
df.Timestamp=pd.to_datetime('2020 '+df.Timestamp)

df.set_index('Timestamp').Value.resample('1H').mean().fillna(0)
Timestamp
2020-01-01 12:00:00     7.5
2020-01-01 13:00:00     5.0
2020-01-01 14:00:00     0.0
2020-01-01 15:00:00     0.0
2020-01-01 16:00:00    18.0
Freq: H, Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

---

Convert the index

```
newdf.index=newdf.index.strftime('%B %d %H:%M')
newdf
Timestamp
January 01 12:00     7.5
January 01 13:00     5.0
January 01 14:00     0.0
January 01 15:00     0.0
January 01 16:00    18.0
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you.  I will look into these options now that I am familiar with them. Much appreciated.

Comment: Can I ask, whats the .Value there accomplishing?

Comment: .Value here is select the column to do the resample mean . it also equal to ['Value'] :-)

Comment: Great, appreciated!